# Term for Methods of Representing Repeated Text in Classifier

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, training, terminology

A colleague told me that there are terms for two different methods of representing repeated text in the training set for a classifier, but he could not recall them. What are the terms for the options described below?

Suppose I want to train a classifier, such as the `scikit-learn` Naive Bayes classifier on sentences extracted from text documents. Any sentence may be appear any number of times in the documents. I have determined the number of instances of each distinct sentence and assigned labels to the ones I will use for training.

**Option 1: One Instance per Distinct Sentence**
I could include in my training set one instance of each distinct sentence. This method gives equal weight to different sentences, regardless of their frequency.

**Option 2: Multiple Instances by Relative Frequency**
I could include in my training set multiple instances of each distinct sentence based on the number of times the sentence appears in the corpus. If the corpus contains 100 instances of Sentence 1 and 25 instances of Sentence 2, then my training set would include four instances of Sentence 1 and one instance of Sentence 2.

This method gives greater weight to sentences that appear more frequently in the corpus.

**Other Options:** Are there related strategies that also have standard names?

Comment: Maybe he had [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf–idf) in mind; it combines _term frequency_ and _inverse document frequency_.

Comment: @Emre My colleague assures me that he was not referring to TF-IDF. We are using a scikit-learn TfidfVectorizer, but that has not affected how we go about selecting samples to submit to the vectorizer.